# xml unmarshalling and comparing to java files

Tags: java, xml, soap, compare, unmarshalling

I'm trying to make program where I could compare values from xml and client inserted values. Program should work like dictionary, just for words that are defined in xml. Here is my code:

```
package rest;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "rest.Translator")
public class TranslatorImp implements Translator{

@Override
public String translate(String rec, String jezik1, String jezik2) {

    for (Word word : words) {

        if(rec.equals(word.getEnglish()) && "english".equals(jezik1) && "serbian".equals(jezik2)){
            return word.getSerbian();

        }else
            if(rec.equals(word.getSerbian()) && "serbian".equals((String)jezik1) && "english".equals((String)jezik2)){
                return word.getEnglish();
            }
    }
    return "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again..";
}
}
```

This is my interface:

```
package rest;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

@WebService
public interface Translator {

    @WebMethod
    String translate(String rec, String jezik1, String jezik2);



    }
```

This is my main class where I've done unmarshaling:

```
package rest;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException{

        JAXBContext jaxbc = JAXBContext.newInstance("word");

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbc.createUnmarshaller();

        Root root = (Root)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("word.xml"));

        List<Word> words = root.getWord();

     }
}
```

And this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Word.xsd">
    <word>
        <english>word</english>
        <serbian>rec</serbian>
    </word>
    <word>
        <english>butterfly</english>
        <serbian>leptir</serbian>
    </word>
    <word>
        <english>house</english>
        <serbian>kuca</serbian>
    </word>
    <word>
        <english>computer</english>
        <serbian>kompjuter</serbian>
    </word>
    <word>
        <english>prison</english>
        <serbian>zatvor</serbian>
    </word>
</root>
```

My unmarshalling classes are:

Word:

```
package rest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="english" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="serbian" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "english",
    "serbian"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "word")
public class Word {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String english;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String serbian;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the english property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getEnglish() {
        return english;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the english property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setEnglish(String value) {
        this.english = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the serbian property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getSerbian() {
        return serbian;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the serbian property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setSerbian(String value) {
        this.serbian = value;
    }

}
```

Root:

```
package rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element ref="{}word" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "word"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<Word> word;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the word property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the word property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getWord().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link Word }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Word> getWord() {
        if (word == null) {
            word = new ArrayList<Word>();
        }
        return this.word;
    }

}
```

And ObjectFactory:

```
package rest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the rest package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: rest
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Root }
     * 
     */
    public Root createRoot() {
        return new Root();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Word }
     * 
     */
    public Word createWord() {
        return new Word();
    }

}
```

So, everything is great except one thing. In my class (first code), list "words" is not recognized. There is tip "Create local variable "words"". So, what should I do when I want to compare unmarshalled values from list (in this case words), and something that I entered through web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TranslatorImp "words" is undefined symbol since it is defined in main method of your Main class. And visibility of that "words" is restricted by that method boundary. You should either move your unmarshalling code to translate method (this will have not that good performance but will let your code catch the changes of the XML file and use up-to-date data from that file) or introduce the mechanism that will allow to communicate the unmarshalled objects from one class to another.